# Long path in powershell and .net

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

We're executing following commands

```
...
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($pathA, $data)
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($pathA, $pathB)
// OR
Expand-Archive $pathA -DestinationPath $pathB
```

on Windows 10 Ent. x64 in versions

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.316
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.316
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

The code works unless $pathB happens to be too long. Tried many suggestions found here

`\\?\$pathB` *does work* in Explorer but in this code fails in `ExtractToDirectory` with

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

and in `Expand-Archive` with

```
Cannot process argument because the value of argument "drive" is null.
```

It shouldn't be a matter of backslash escaping, if I doubled them it gave me

```
Illegal characters in path
```

Also tried `New-PSDrive` as in

```
New-PSDrive -Name "X" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $pathBase
```

but I'm getting

```
 A drive with the name 'X' does not exist.
```

I read that it needs `-Persist`, which gives me

```
 ...the root must be a file system location on a remote computer.
```

Tried

```
net use x: $pathBase
// OR
subst $pathBase "x:\"

Join-Path -Path "x:\" -ChildPath ...
```

and both end in

```
Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'x' does not exist.
```

Are any of these used wrong? If not - what else to try to fix this?
Thank you

Comment: What versions of Windows, Powershell and Net Framework are you running on? Long path support is a semi-new thing, at least so far as net framework (which powershell classic runs on) is concerned. You might be able to set some powershell configurations to enable it, assuming proper framework is installed. It's kinda old but see if this link helps https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/

Comment: Thank you! Added versions, if it's missing something can you please hint how to get what is needed? I will check your link

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 only long path without \\?\ prefix is new. Long path has been supported since the advent of NTFS and the NT kernel decades ago

Comment: @phuclv right except netframework prior to 4.6.2 had a MAX_PATH constant defined (260 or 258 iirc) and the framework enforced the limit. It sounds like his destination paths exceed that

Comment: You said `\\?\$pathB` does not work. But does `$pathB = $pathB.Insert(0,"\\?\")` followed by running your command work?